# How can I access AJAX defined variable gloabally?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I created a variable in AJAX success function which I want to use for another AJAX call outside that function. I tried to store it with local storage and then use it  but could not access the variable. Any idea as to how can I access it?

Here is the code:-

```
var c_id = 110;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {'id':c_id},
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1/Student Back End/sbms.php',
        success : function(data){
            var quant_presta = data.quantity;
            localStorage.setItem('Presta_Quant',quant_presta);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('Presta_Quant'));
        },
        error : function(data){
            //console.log(data.name.quantity);
            $('#fetch_error').show();
            $('#fetch_error').fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I posted the working code from the answer by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the code ..

```
$.ajax({
 url : '',
 success: function(data){
  myFunction(data);
 }
});

function myFunction(data){
  // do the processing here. You can access this from all ajax calls.
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error unexpected token ; on calling the function in success. Why is that?

Comment: You are defining a new function in success ..

`success : function(data){
          foo(data); // remove function
}`

Comment: Yeah just saw this. Thanks a lot!!